# Edit session for wrong spelling of mathematicians and mathematical concepts

Tags: discussion, editing, spelling

Wrong spelling of mathematician's names and mathematical concepts is perpetuated by their presence in highly indexed resources like stackexchange.

I think that the internet would become a better place if someone edited the 179 instances of [Cauchy-Schwartz](http://spikedmath.com/170.html)(versus 1203 instances of Cauchy-Schwarz) on this site.

Evidently, bumping 179 old questions to the front page would not be regarded favourably, and proposals to fix this situations are status-declined (and I have no idea if there are some limits on the number of edits a single user can make per time unit).

So, I am asking if we could have some "fix-orthography evening". We could collect a list of egregious mathematically relevant spelling mistakes and fix them in one go to keep the impact on normal questions minimal.

[Some further reading on the topic.](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/courses/math696/spelling-lesson.html)

Comment: As it has waited this long, it could perhaps wait a little longer. I would presume Christmas/new year would be the best time to do this (as I presume the traffic is least then). Of course, someone would gave to have a 6-month memory...

Comment: Bumping three questions, twice a day, makes this a month long project. Alongside with quick editing of new questions that enter the fold, make that two months. It's a project, but that's how we ended the mixing of [set-theory] and [elementary-set-theory].

Comment: I once cleared the site of "continous". It now appears over 750 times :(

Comment: @user147263 Most Cauchy-Schwartz occurences are without a hyphen.

Comment: [This old thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8698/11619) lists several common incorrect spellings. Largely about incorrect versions of diacritical marks. Do observe that translitteration (of Russian names in particular - I guess Chinese could be same) is not always a well-defined function.

Comment: Do we want to edit old posts with zero upvotes, or should they be allowed to fade into the background and forgotten?

Comment: I remember the same idea mentioned [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2443654#2443654), although probably not too seriously. I do not remember this being discussed on meta before. (BTW Srivatsan did quite a lot of edits of common misspellings. I will definitely not be against if some users will work on something like this. It is definitely an improvement of the site content.)

Comment: These are all good points. So I will edit a few questions a day. As far as the zero upvotes posts go, I will simply start with recent and upvoted posts which should mean that most zero-upvote posts disappear anyway.

Comment: @user1729 I thought about this on occassion (in general), and I rather think one should do such things when traffic is *high* not low. The issue is that the bumped stuff gets deluted better and dissapears more quickly.

Comment: If anyone is keeping a list, "Lebesque" should be on it. I don't know whether this spelling shows up all that much here, but it's so common in published literature that you need to make a separate search with this spelling when doing a serious search for any phrase that includes his name.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using a script or some form of automation?

Comment: I saw a similar problem with ["lamda" on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Lamda) a week or two ago, but deleted my meta question once I started attempting to fix them: most have other issues.

Comment: Referenced in [an Über meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383433/can-the-link-replacement-tool-be-used-on-typos-in-regular-text) in 2022.